# Selective news from a particular rss newsfeed

Tags: android, parse-platform, rss

In my application I want to display RSS feed of a particular website. But I do not want it to display full Rss feed, I want only some particular tags to be searched and display and  only its related links should display on screen.

here is my code of the Parser Class:-

```
package com.example.sara.rssfeed;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.util.Xml;

import com.example.sara.rssfeed.RssItem;

public class PcWorldRssParser {

    // We don't use namespaces
    private final String ns = null;

    public List<RssItem> parse(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(inputStream, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return readFeed(parser);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private List<RssItem> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "rss");
        String title = null;
        String link = null;
        List<RssItem> items = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("title")) {
                title = readTitle(parser);}

               else if (name.equals("link")) {
                   link = readLink(parser);}


            if (title=="Top Stories - Google News" && link=="http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&amp;ned=us") {
                RssItem item = new RssItem(title, link);
                items.add(item);
                title = null;
                link = null;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");
        String link = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
        return link;
    }

    private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
        String title = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
        return title;
    }

    // For the tags title and link, extract their text values.
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Error:

> on line  if (title=="Top Stories - Google News" &&
>   link=="http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&ned=us")`if I put`
>   tittle!=null`and`link!=null`

it displays full rss feed. but If i give it particular link and title tag to search it displays nothing, only a blank screen.

Please help what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I recommend logging to see what `title` and `link` actually gives you, it may not be what you think it is.

Comment: Do you know any other way to get filter RSS newsfeed so that it provides only user desired news???